# Check if an element exists in a 2d array and return something if true

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, matrix

I'm not all that familiar with using multidimensional arrays and here I'm trying to see if an element exists in a 2d array and if it does, I want some sort of indication.

```
// initialize an array 3x3
int matrix[3][3]; 
bool found = false;
// The matrix will be loaded with all 0 values, let's assume this has been done.

// Check if there are any 0's left in the matrix...

for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++){
    for(int y = 0; y < 3; y++){
        if(matrix[x][y] == 0){
           break; // << HERE I want to exit the entire loop.
        }else{
            continue; // Continue looping till you find a 0, if none found then break out and make: found = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use that `found` variable. Remove `continue`; it's not as if your loop would do anything else without.

Comment: You will need to set some flag (e.g., bool variable) before break. Then, check the flag outside the inner loop and break again if necessary. This will break out of both loops.
You don't need that continue statement.

Comment: Make it a function and simply return from it when found, code would be cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A control flag will be useful:

```
bool found = false;
for (unsigned int row = 0; (!found) && (row < MAX_ROWS); ++ row)
{
  for (unsigned int column = 0; (!found) && (column < MAX_COLUMNS); ++ column)
  {
    if (matrix[row][column] == search_value)
    {
       found = true;
    }
  }
}
```

**Edit 1:**
If you want to preserve the `row` and `column` values then you need to `break` out of each loop:

```
bool found = false;
for (unsigned int row = 0; (!found) && (row < MAX_ROWS); ++ row)
{
  for (unsigned int column = 0; (!found) && (column < MAX_COLUMNS); ++ column)
  {
    if (matrix[row][column] == search_value)
    {
       found = true;
       break;
    }
  }
  if (found)
  {
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
int matrix[3][3];
bool found = false;


for(int x = 0; x < 3 && found == false; x++)
  {
    for(int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
     {
       if(matrix[x][y] == 0)
       {
          found = true;
          break; 
       }
     }
 }
if (found)
 cout<<"0 exists in the matrix";
else
 cout<<"0 doesn't exist in the matrix";
```

Comment: Why do you need the `continue` statement?

Comment: There are huge problems with this, it won't return anything if there **isn't** any zeros in the array. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Why are you using `c` as a flag and the `found` variable as a flag?

Comment: You could simplify by using `if (found) cout << "0 exists in the matrix\n";`  No need for the `c` variable.

Comment: If `x == 1` and `found == true`, your outer loop will iterate again.

Comment: @Toby if 0 is found out the value of found becomes true otherwise it remains false as initiated and else statement will be executed.